# Difference tool becomes unresponsive and causes QGIS (2.18.24) to crash

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2

I'm trying to find the difference between two layers (the first is a manitoba wide shapefile and the second is a layer that narrows down the water bodies of manitoba selected from another canadian waterbodies shapefile). Both layers have the same CRS (after modification). I'm trying to create a new layer that shows me only the land area of manitoba (minus the water bodies) but the difference tool keeps crashing on me. What exactly is going wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd try with QGIS 3.4 - 2.18 is no longer supported.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: 311 layer is a 54 Clipped layer? In addition to the wise advice of [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson), the steps that I would follow are: Having both layers and the project, all in the same CRS; _Multipart to singleparts_ both layers; _Clip_ the 54 layer with the 211 layer; _Difference_ between 211 layer and 54 clipped layer.